# Grounded Coplanar - Impedence calculation of microstrip - Advance Design System software (ADS)

Tags: ground, microstrip, ads

I want to calculate the impedance of the micro-strip using Advance design system (ADS) software. I cannot locate "GROUNDED CO-PLANAR" or anything like that. I am new to this software. Can anybody help? 
I want to calculate the GAP/Clearance constraint for the microstrip shown in the picture for 50-OHM . [image]

Answer (score 2):

The model in ads called CPWG -  Coplanner waveguide with lower ground plane. 
You can find it both in the line calc and the copplanar transmission line library.